# Find digits of n number integer with a mathematical formula.

Tags: functions, number-systems

Consider a number abcde. Here, we have 5 digits in that number. Let, say this abcde = n. Then I want a single mathematical function which tells how much digits are there in n. 
They could be 3 or 100. 
In programming it's easy but it requires more statements. Is this possible to get a single statement. Generally, I not want this for programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n$ is a positive integer, the number of decimal digits of $n$ is $\left\lfloor{\log_{10}(n)}\right\rfloor+1$.

Explanation:

Let $n$ be a positive integer.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&n\;\text{is a $k$-digit number}\\[4pt]
\iff\;&10^{k-1}\le n < 10^{k}\\[4pt]
\iff\;&k-1\le \log_{10}(n) < k\\[4pt]
\iff\;&k-1=\left\lfloor{\log_{10}(n)}\right\rfloor\\[4pt]
\iff\;&k=\left\lfloor{\log_{10}(n)}\right\rfloor+1\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Comment: Can you send me link to learn how to write equation and formulas here. Is this site use LaTex?

Comment: @umairmughal $\lfloor\log_{10} 95\rfloor +1= \lfloor 1.977\rfloor +1=1+1=2$

Comment: @umairmughal Refer to https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference  for Mathjax tutorial